# "Sprite Pack" for room themes in level generation. Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, sprite, unity3d-2dtools

So I was wondering if there is a way to "repack" sprites to be a theme. I got 1 image with all the stage sprites I need and I basically wondered if I can keep them in that 1 image and then have "links" or something to a seperate pack.
I thought of doing a "Theme" class and then create instances of that to match my themes, with variables hardcoded to match. But I can't believe there isn't a better way.
I hope I've explained this well enough ^^

Comment: It might work to load the image (resources.loadall) and sort the sprites into different containers (e.g. lists) by a prefix in the name. This would at least avoid hardcoding of all the single sprites.

Comment: Or you create public arrays/lists and drag the sprites into them in the inspector.

Comment: FTR if you use 2dToolkit, this is automatic - it's one of the reasons people still use it so much even though Unity has 2D now.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this, for those interested, and it seems to work. Though it does leave me having to code the textures in the code like, I was looking for a way to it be done in the editor/folder structure.

```
ThemePack t = new ThemePack(Room.Theme.Medbay);
t.walls.Add(sprites[6]);
t.floors.Add(sprites[32]);
t.floors.Add(sprites[66]);
t.floors.Add(sprites[67]);
t.floors.Add(sprites[68]);
t.floors.Add(sprites[69]);
```

---

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class SpriteCollection {
    private Sprite[] sprites;
    private string[] names;

    public Sprite this[int i] {
        get {
            return sprites[i];
        }
    }

    public SpriteCollection(string spritesheet) {
        sprites = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>(spritesheet);
        names = new string[sprites.Length];

        for(int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++) {
            names[i] = sprites[i].name;
        }
    }

    public Sprite GetSprite(string name) {
        return sprites[System.Array.IndexOf(names, name)];
    }
}
```

---

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Level;

public class ThemePack {
    public List<Sprite> walls;
    public List<Sprite> floors;

    public Room.Theme name {get; set;} //Could use a string instead, but this is an enum already existing.

    private ThemePack() {
    }

    public ThemePack(Room.Theme n, List<Sprite> w, List<Sprite> f) {
        name = n;
        walls = w;
        floors = f;
    }

    public ThemePack (Room.Theme n) : this(n, new List<Sprite>(), new List<Sprite>()) {
    }

    public Sprite GetRandomWall() {
        return walls[Random.Range(0, walls.Count - 1)];
    }

    public Sprite GetRandomFloor() {
        return floors[Random.Range(0, floors.Count - 1)];
    }
}
```